# How do you get all videos' id, title and tags?

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My goal is to append id, title and tags to an array `arr` of all videos of a youtube channel.

This is what I tried

```
client = get_authenticated_service()
results1 = search_list_by_keyword(client,
  part='snippet',
  maxResults=50,
  channelId=someChannelId)  
for z in range(len(results1['items'])):  
  #print(results1['items'][z]['id'])     
  try:  
    id = results1['items'][z]['id']['videoId']
  except:
    continue;    
  results2 = videos_list_by_id(client,
      part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
      id=id)
  title = results2['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
  tags = results2['items'][0]['snippet']['tags']             
  print (title) 
  row = []
  row.append(id)
  row.append(title)
  row.append(tags)   
  if 'something' not in tags:
    arr.append(row)
nextPageToken = results1['nextPageToken']  
while 1==1: 
  try:
    print 'Continue at %s:' % (nextPageToken)   
    results1 = search_list_by_keyword(client,
      part='snippet',
      maxResults=50,
      channelId=someChannelId,
      pageToken=nextPageToken)
    nextPageToken = results1['nextPageToken']
    for z in range(len(results1['items'])): 
      id = results1['items'][z]['id']['videoId'] 
      results2 = videos_list_by_id(client,
          part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
          id=id)
      title = results2['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
      tags = results2['items'][0]['snippet']['tags']       
      print (title) 
      if 'Podcast' in tags:
        tags.remove('Podcast')
      row = []
      row.append(id)
      row.append(title)
      row.append(tags)   
      if 'something' not in tags:
        arr.append(row)
  except:
    break
```

and

```
def search_list_by_keyword(client, **kwargs):
  # See full sample for function
  kwargs = remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs)

  response = client.search().list(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  return response
```

it works till `while 1==1`, after that I get less and less results printed by `print (title)`. And the final amount of titles is about half the total amount of public videos of the channel.

How do I get all videos' id, title and tags?

Comment: If you just want to get all videos and its id, title and tag just use a simple [video list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). Add fields `items(id,snippet(tags,title))` to specify to only what you need. Just start with listing first before implementing other filters or codes to verify if you are getting all videos, ids, tags and titles. Hope this helps.

Comment: video list: "This example retrieves information about a specific video. It uses the id parameter to identify the video.". But to get all videos, I need to get the ids first. Or are you talking about sth different?

Comment: You are correct, you have to use `search.list` first before `video.list`. Are you filtering a tag with this line `if 'something' not in tags:`? May I suggest to try printing your initial list of videos of channel, then print each `tag`, `title` and `ID` of the video without any filtering.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot The `print (title)`-part shows that too little is being generated, and this is what I am referring to.

Comment: What I meant was after printing the title, print each video result corresponding to the title to see how many videos are not fetch. It is pretty weird because you've already placed the result into the array.